# Android: Material Design Chip - show close icon only when selected

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

I'm using Material Chip and I want to show `closeIcon` only when the `Chip` is selected.


How can I achieve this behavior? I can do some binding etc, but I would prefer some simplier solution.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:chipSpacing="8dp"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:singleSelection="false">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/chip_1"
                style="@style/MyChipStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_cross_white_24dp"
                app:closeIconEnabled="true"
                app:checkedIconEnabled="false"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:text="Example text" />

        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add code for checking that chip is selected or not.

Try below code to check:

```
private void chipCloseBtnVisi(){
    if(chip_1.isChecked()){
        // If Chip is selected(checked) then show close icon
        chip_1.setCloseIconVisible(true);
    }else{
        // If Chip is not selected(checked) then hide close icon
        chip_1.setCloseIconVisible(false);
    }
}
```

To change check state, need to add `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to chip

```
chip_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                chipCloseBtnVisi();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm aware that it can be done using code or some bindings. I was just curious if there is any simplier way to setup it in xml layout itself without any additional logic.